# Angular material how to get position of md-switch to be on the right side?

Tags: angular-material

Can anyone help how to position the md-switch to the right handside of the text?

```
    <md-switch class="md-primary" md-no-ink aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model="filter.fulldayView">
        Full day view
    </md-switch>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `md-invert` in the `md-switch` tag which is available for Release 1.1.2 and later.

**UPDATE**:

For releases before 1.1.2, 
try using the following css. You can use id tag for apply these styles to only a specific `md-switch`.

```
md-switch#switch1 {
  position: relative;
}

#switch1 div.md-container {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10%;
    float: right;
}

#switch1 div.md-label {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

html:

```
<md-switch md-no-ink ng-model="hasInk" aria-label="No Ink Effects" id="switch1">
    Switch 1
</md-switch>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/nehal90/pen/pwabyj)

Comment: Yes, it is in the doc. but for some reason it is not working at all.

Comment: Which version of material are you using?

Comment: I am using verson 1.1.0

Comment: Ahh, that's why `md-invert` is not working, it was introduced in version 1.1.2